# Group randomly List of Lists as N subsets with K elements in each

Tags: java, algorithm, random

I have the following list of lists List<List<Integer>>

```
1 2
3
4 5 6
7
8
9
10
```

I have to group randomly this list of lists as 3 subsets with 4 elements each (nevermind that in the last subset i'll have less than 4 elements), and in every subset i cant have elements from the same row ( i cant have 3 4 5 7 for example). What should be the basic algorithm????

Comment: I see no question, you must be wanting the solution. OK, What have you tried so far?

Comment: You have made a statement. Now ask a question.

Comment: first i tried to sort by size in the inner list so i had: 4 5 6, 1 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10 and get random element from the outer list (for example i got 1 2) then i get random from this list (for example i pick 2) and this is goes in my first subset and same till the end, buuuuuuuuuut when selecting random sub lists from the outer list i have situation that for the last subset i have to put (4 5 6) and i'm not allowed to do this :/ (this algorighm not allways works and this is not acceptable for me)

Comment: I would sort rows by numbers of elements. Then, take a random number in the 4 first non empty rows. (Then delete each taken element from the corresponding row).

Comment: @Jason : The sorting is intended for the "`every subset i cant have elements from the same row`" part.

Comment: It was actually to imply some randomness. Without this, the algorithm is deterministic which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: it will be fine even if someone tells me how can i do this mathematically i'll code it

Comment: @anfy2002us: Already [done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18192123/45914).

Answer (score 4):

> What should be the basic algorithm????

Pluck four random elements from each of the first four<sup>1</sup> randomly chosen non-empty lists in the list of lists. Remove the chosen items, and repeat for the next subset. Remove empty lists as you go.

Next, you need to note that not all of your inputs are solvable:

```
1
2
3
4
5 6 7 8 9
```

In this case, we choose randomly

```
1*
2*
3*
4
5 6 7 8 9*
```

-> 7 1 2 3 (chosen randomly)

```
[]
[]
[]
4*
5 6 8 9*
```

-> 5 4 . . <- uh, impossible to choose four items from different lists even though non-empty lists remain. You can detect this during iteration.

<sup>1</sup>: Or, choose randomly from all of the lists if less than four non-empty lists remain.

Comment: by basic i mean i dont want snippets or code i just wanted something that u did, but in your example the elements are not picked random, they are picked as they are put in the list, this is not so random for me :/

Comment: I don't think this works for every case. For example : row 1: {1} row 2: {2} row 3: {3} row 4: {4} row 5: {5,6,7,8,9}. After the first step, you only have the 5th row : {5,6,7,8,9}. The problem is that you can't take 2 elements from the same row.

Comment: @anfy2002us: Then pick them randomly if that's an essential requirement.

Comment: @Jason yeah but when picking them randomly i have the situation that i have 5 6, 2 (from your first snippet) and 5 6 are on the same row :/

Comment: @anfy2002us: No, pick *randomly* from the row when you are choosing a single item from it.

Comment: @Amaud Denoyelle: That case is impossible to solve. With three sets, one of the sets *must* contain two items from the 5th row.

Comment: Your solution does NOT give all possible answers with equal likelihood.

Comment: @btilly: Thanks for the comment, you're right although note that this isn't specified although *probably* tacitly assumed.

Comment: I don't think picking randomly is a good idea. [Pick from the lists with the most elements.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18205139/1711796).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is to perform a random selection, check whether your "no two from the same" rule is violated. If it is, then throw away and try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the lists by number of elements.
2. Pick 4 elements, one from each of the 4 lists with the most elements.
3. Resort.
4. Repeat from 2.

A [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) could help here.

**Why do we need to pick from the lists with the most elements?**

Consider this case:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7
8
```

If we pick both 7 and 8, we'll be left with something like:

```
1 2
3
5
```

From here there's no possible way to pick 4 elements from different lists.

However, if we pick elements from the lists with the most elements, we'd be left with something like:

```
1
3
5
8
```

From here we can just pick one element from each list.